# Gravity Forms Salesforce API Add-On - field mapping not saving

Tags: wordpress, salesforce

I am using WP 3.5, Gravity Forms 1.6.11 and Gravity Forms Salesforce API Add-On 2.2.3 (without Web-to-Leads add-on activated) and an Unlimited Salesforce account.

I am having issues with the field list not showing until I save the feed and come back into it and then refresh objects & fields.  Once the fields display I map them and click Update Feed and all the fields, including the mapping, disappear again.

I have deactivated and even deleted and reinstalled the Gravity Forms Salesforce API Add-On but no change in behavior.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Contact their dedicated support? Search their forums?

Comment: Already searched their forums but the Salesforce API Add-On isn't built be the people who build Gravity Forms so they don't support it or have anything in their forums on it.